# Using Range.Offset but "User-defined type not defined" popup in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I write a simple function in the Modules as follow:

```
Function allocate(ByVal pq As PriceQtyClass, ByVal al As AllocationClass) As Boolean

    Dim tmpRange As Range
    Dim tmpDic As Dictionary
    Dim rowIndex As Integer

    Set tmpDic = pq.priQtyDic
    Set tmpRange = Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    rowIndex = 1

    For Each k In tmpDic
        set tmpRange = k 'adding set here isnot working
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next

End Function
```

When it goes to tmpRange = k， Message with "User-defined type not defined" popup!

I don't know why it is and where is wrong!

Please help!

Comment: add `Set` before error line, like `Set tmpRange = k`... hoping k is any type of range.

Comment: @kaz is right but how is priQtyDic defined?

Comment: To iterate over the entries in dictionary tmpDic, you have to use tmpDic.Keys() It might make things clearer to start with an "Option Explicit" line and to add a "Dim k as Range" declaration.

Comment: @AxelKemper is pretty much there. On your `Set tmprange = k` line, this would then need to change (after the change suggested by @Axel) to `Set tmpRange = tpmDic(k)`

Comment: I'm afraid adding Set before tmpRange would NOT help. I found the root reason which is in Function we can't mulipulate the cells.